# Google two factor authentication rejects login from Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

Since I turned on the two-factor login in googlemail, I cannot login from Thunderbird anymore. (Before it was all fine.)

What do I have to change in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to get a 'Application-specific' password from Google. You can do this on the Security section of your Accounts page. Click on Settings in the 2-step verification section.

Here's the link to the Google help page on [application-specific passwords](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=ch_b/0/SmsAuthConfig&answer=185833).

Answer (score 2):

Through no fault of Brad Google changed the process. I tried to follow the instructions Brad shared, from the website 
Aplication-speccific password: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en&ctx=ch_b/0/SmsAuthConfig

One moment: Before you go enabling things that you might not understand go here
https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity

if everything check out, meaning you trust all the locations and apps accessing you account then proceed to the next step

You will have to go here and enable, Access for less secure apps.
https://www.google.com/settings/security

Please heed any warning that good gives you!

Happy Thunderbirding.

Answer (score 2):

1, You have to generate a password for an app. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en&ctx=ch_b/0/SmsAuthConfig
(Remember to copy the password, you have to use it later)

2, Setting the Thunderbird mail client, using the password generated on the first step. You should pass the password check now. 
(Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 on 22 Dic 2014)